# s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: Content is invalid. Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm working on an XSD for a project, here's what I've got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Elizabeth schema" 
xmlns:elz="http://www.example.org/Elizabeth_schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name ="year">
<xs:complexType mixed = "true">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="entry">
    <xs:complexType mixed ="true">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:attribute name ="when" type = "xs:string"/> 
        <xs:attribute name = "place" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "items" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "characters">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="character" type = "xs:string"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name = "eventscollection">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name = "type" type = "xs:string"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name ="entrytxt">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:any minOccurs = "0"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I haven't pointed the xls at the schema yet because I want to get the schema working first.  My IDE is throwing me a bug:

> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_entryyear' is
>   invalid.  Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too
>   often.

Line 11 is where I introduce the first attribute under the element "entry."  I've found that if I delete line 10 ("simpleContent"), I get the same error but on line 13 where I introduce the first element under "entry."

I'm a beginner with this, and I've done some prodding around the internet but can't seem to figure out what's up with my code.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your XSD, including

- `entry` does not have simple content.  Change `xs:simpleContent` to
  `xs:sequence` within `xs:complexType`.
- Then, move the `xs:attribute` declarations outside of `xs:sequence`.
- Remove `minOccurs` from `xs:anyAttribute`.

Note that you probably want to remove the spacing surrounding your attribute `=` sign -- not required, but it looks rather unconventional, and inconsistent as you have it.

Here is your XSD fully corrected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Elizabeth schema"
           xmlns:elz="http://www.example.org/Elizabeth_schema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="year">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="items" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="characters">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="character" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="eventscollection">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="entrytxt">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:anyAttribute/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="when" type="xs:string"/> 
            <xs:attribute name="place" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate the help.